# Write to file in iOS/macOS Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift-playground

is there any way to write a file from a pure Swift Playgrounds? (Not in Xcode, but either in the iOS Playgrounds app, or the new Playground.app for macOS).

In Playgrounds for Xcode we can do:

```
let fileUrl = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

To write to the playground directory.

On macOS/iOS Playgrounds app, this is not available. We can add resources to the Playground and read those in both of these cases, so maybe there is a way to write a file to the resource bundle as well?